# Imprimir el response de una api

Tags: javascript, nodejs

desde el front estoy intentando imprimir los resultados del backend, que devuelve usuarios. La api responde con un objeto dentro de un arreglo. Intente de la siguiente manera desde el back respuesta[0], pero no me funciona

```
    const getUsers =async (req,res)=>{
  const conexion = await connection.find();
  console.log('conexion ',conexion);
  res.send(conexion);
  return conexion;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde el front me imprime esto

```
const URL = 'http://localhost:4000/api/users';
    const resultado = await fetch(URL);
    console.log('resultado ',resultado)
    return resultado;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para que puedas utilizar la respuesta que te da tu api en el front, debes convertir la respuesta que del `fetch` a un objeto de javascript utilizando el método `json`.

Basta con agregar esta línea debajo de `conexion`:

```
conexion = await conexion.json();
```

Recuerda utilizar `let` si quieres usar el mismo nombre, ya que definiste `conexion` con `const`.

Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
const peticion = async () => {
    const URL = 'https://api.itbook.store/1.0/search/mongodb';
    let conexion = await fetch(URL);
    conexion = await conexion.json();
    console.log('resultado ',conexion)
    return conexion;}
 
peticion();
```